# Mongodb c#driver - AggregateToCollectionOperation

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the library MongoDB.Driver 2.8.1 (i'm planning to upgrade to the latest version, it's an old project).

I'm trying to use the operator $out for a query in my code so I wrote this piece of code (it's not wonderful, but it's not a problem)

```
await collectionAcc.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(@"{
                    $unwind: {
                        path: ""$Packs"",
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
                    }
                }")
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(@"{
                    $replaceRoot: {
                                 newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ ""$$ROOT"", {""Sku"" : ""$Packs.Sku"" }, {""SizePack"" : ""$Packs.Size"" } ] }
                            }
                }")
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(@"{ $out: ""accessoryPacks"" }").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I run it and this error appear:
"The pipeline for an AggregateOperation contains a $out operator. Use AggregateOutputToCollectionOperation instead"

Good, I try to use AggregateOutputToCollectionOperation class but I found no documentation at all, nor a decent example.

Someone can help me?

Comment: it's strange, you should not use `AggregateOutputToCollectionOperation` directly. Are you sure that `$out` is the last stage in your aggregate pipeline?

Comment: @dododo Yes it is. I post the code I use as is. I changed nothing.
collectionAcc is initialized as 

`var collectionAcc = _mdb.GetCollection<Accessory>("accessory");`

_mdb is of type IMongoDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

oh, I missed that you call `FirstOrDefault`. `$out` and `$merge` should be the last stages in pipeline, but FirstOrDefault additionally adds `{ limit : 1 }` stage after them. You should add this stage inside pipeline before `$out`